# Check constraint in sql server 2008 with ltrim and rtrim functions

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using below code to add constraint on `CreatID` column. But its not working. I can still add text like `'   xyz'` which I don't want to. Also when only spaces are there in text it should be considered as `'null'` value. Like if I enter `'<space><space><space>'` this then it should be considered as null.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OneC_Gadget_AppDetails]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD  CONSTRAINT [chk_CreateID_val] 
    CHECK  ((len(ltrim(rtrim([AppActionContent])))>(1)))
```

Comment: I think the condition should be: `CHECK len(ltrim(rtrim( AppActionContent ))) = len( AppActionContent )`

Comment: @Mahmoud: You are right, `DATALENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(AppActionContent))) = DATALENGTH(AppActionContent)` should be used to check for both leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: What the OP posted, ensures that there are at least 2 non-space characters in the field.

Comment: @ypercube: it tried this but it gives- Incorrect syntax error near 'len'/'datalenghth'.

Comment: @ypercube: nop..It gives different errors for ltrim as Incorrect syntax expecting select, AppAction content as Incorrect syntax expecting select and for len as Expecting NOT_FOR or '('

Comment: It works in [SQL-Fiddle test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0de59/1), with: `CHECK ( DATALENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(AppActionContent))) = DATALENGTH(AppActionContent) )`. Some of the other code you have (before the ALTER TABLE statement perhaps) has a syntax error.